# How do I apply styles to an element with a specific class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want every link in the `container-1` div to have the property `text-decoration: underline;`. How can I achieve this without also changing the `container-5` div's links?

```
<div class="container-1">
    <div class="container-2">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>

        <div class="container-3">
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </div
    </div>

    <div class="container-4">
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-5">
    <div class="container-6">
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>

        <div class="container-7">
            <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        </div
    </div>

    <div class="container-8">
        <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very basic css - I would recommend doing a basic tutorial so you can get to grips with it - if you don't know how to this then you aren't going to be able to do much else and you are probably going to annoy the SO community with very basic questions that can be answered with a little research

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is very basic css and can be learnt by looking at any tutorial

Comment: This may be extremely basic, but it's technically not off-topic. "Basic" is not a valid close reason @Pete

Comment: @Pete The appropriate response to perceived lack of effort is downvote, not close vote.

Comment: @Pete You are punishing the OP in your own way by voting to close the question as off-topic. The question is about how to do something with CSS; it's not off-topic, end of story.

Comment: @Pete No one was rude til your last comment, Please remember to [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). If the question is a duplicate, please find one. I looked for one when this question came up in the CV Queue because, as you said, it is very basic. Having not found one, I voted Leave Open, because it is otherwise **on-topic**. Just because you are too lazy to do the right thing and look for a dupe doesn't mean you should take an incorrect action and suggest it is off-topic for some other, made-up reason.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask what is the first 2 lines OP shows no sign of that and I wasn't being rude in the last comment - I was just repeating what you said back to you if you don't like being told end of story then don't use it yourself and anyway I'm not too bothered about what you think as I have been doing the same sort of voting since I joined and no-one else has complained so have a good day

Answer (score 3):

You select the parent div of the links you want to style, in this case `.container-2` and select all the links using `a`. Then you style all the links in the parent div to your liking, in this case with the property `text-decoration: underline;`

Link 4, 5 and 6 are in container 5 and will not be styled since you didn't select them.

Because all links are underlined by default, I included `color: red;` to show that it works.

EDIT: Fixed typo in snippet

```css
.container-2 a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-1">
    <div class="container-2">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>

        <div class="container-3">
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        </div
    </div>

    <div class="container-4">
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-5">
    <div class="container-6">
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>

        <div class="container-7">
            <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        </div
    </div>

    <div class="container-8">
        <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS class selector:

```
.container-1 a{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Also, read [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to get started with CSS selector, and [this one](https://code.tutsplus.com/en/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) to go further in with CSS3 selectors.

Comment: While W3Schools is much better than they used to be, I would still recommend against sharing that site as a tutorial destination; the Mozilla Developer Network would be a much better source, as it is a wiki and so does not suffer from the same accuracy errors as W3Schools often does.

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you for commenting @TylerH.